# [Golang]Different about call a method with pointer type, using point type or struct type?

Tags: pointers, go

Like the title said, I don't know the different when I use the struct type or pointer type when call the method `Greeting()` in my case, does the call `p.Greeting()` and `u.Greeting()` just same? Seems no performance different either, when call the `Greeting()` method.

I think `u.Greeting()` is automatically convert to `(&u).Greeting()`?

[Everything in Go is passed by value](http://golang.org/doc/faq#pass_by_value), but I think in this case, the caller `u` is passing by reference or pointer.

```
package main

import "fmt"

type User struct {
    Name string
}

func (u *User) Greeting() string {
    u.Name = u.Name+" modify"
    return fmt.Sprintf("Greetings %s!", u.Name)
}

func main() {
    p := &User{"cppgohan by pointer"}
    u := User{"cppgohan by value"}

    fmt.Println(p.Greeting(), p)
    fmt.Println(u.Greeting(), u)
}
```

Output:

```
Greetings cppgohan by pointer modify! &{cppgohan by pointer modify}
Greetings cppgohan by value modify! {cppgohan by value modify}
```

Comment: Go has a rule where the language implicitly takes a pointer / dereferences if you try to call a method on a variable whose type is "very similar" to that of the receiver (only differs in indirection).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `p`, calling `Greeting()` is simply calling `p.Greeting()`, for `u` it's calling `(&u).Greeting()`.

[Example](http://play.golang.org/p/k8xWcu50re):

```
func (u *User) Greeting() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("Greetings %s [%p]!", u.Name, u)
}

func main() {
    p := &User{"cppgohan by pointer"}
    u := User{"cppgohan by value"}
    pu := &u

    fmt.Printf("[%p] %v %v\n", pu, pu.Greeting(), pu)
    fmt.Printf("[%p] %v %v\n", &u, u.Greeting(), u)
    fmt.Printf("[%p] %v %v\n", p, p.Greeting(), p)
}
```

Output:

> [0x1030e0e0] Greetings cppgohan by value [**0x1030e0e0**]! &{cppgohan by value}
>
> [0x1030e0e0] Greetings cppgohan by value [**0x1030e0e0**]! {cppgohan by value}
>
> [0x1030e0d8] Greetings cppgohan by pointer [0x1030e0d8]! &{cppgohan by pointer}

Notice how the first 2 have the same address because it's implicitly converted to a pointer.

Comment: Thanks for making me understand! Next time I'll figure it myself.